# How to get the latest release tag in git and the distance to HEAD

Tags: git

Using https://github.com/google/glog as an example. The latest release is 0.3.5.

After searching hours on stackoverflow and google, I am not able to find a correct answer.

```
git describe
```

shows

```
v0.3.3-147-gb3695ee
```

and

```
git describe --tags
```

shows

```
v0.3.4-133-gb3695ee
```

and

```
git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`
```

shows

```
v0.3.5
```

What command should I type in order to get

```
v0.3.5-41-gb3695ee
```

Comment: Is `v.0.3.5` a predecessor of your current HEAD? Which commit have you checked out? What does `git rev-parse HEAD` say? I ask because `gb3695ee` which is shown in your describe outputs does not exist as a commit in the repository you refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your command use is correct, and it's more of a repo/branch issue.

Briefly, from the [describe](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) documentation:

> The command finds the most recent tag that is reachable from a commit.
>   If the tag points to the commit, then only the tag is shown.
>   Otherwise, it suffixes the tag name with the number of additional
>   commits on top of the tagged object and the abbreviated object name of
>   the most recent commit.
>
> By default (without --all or --tags) git describe only shows annotated
>   tags. For more information about creating annotated tags see the -a
>   and -s options to git-tag.

So if the desired tag isn't being shown using `git describe`, we can assume it's either:

- Not reachable from the current commit.
- Not an annotated tag.
- Not an existing tag.

To show non-annotated tags, we can used `git describe --tags`. Since this seems to give us a different tag, but not the one you're after, we can probably conclude that the tag you're interested in either doesn't exist, or is not reachable from the current branch.

I cloned the repo in question and ran `git tag --list` which does show a selection of tags including `0.3.3`, `0.3.4`, and `0.3.5`.
So it seems the tag exists, but must not be on the `master` branch.
We can confirm this with `git branch --contains <commit>`, where `<commit>`will be `0.3.5`. If you haven't yet cloned any remote branches, this will give you no results.

We can run `git branch -r --contains <commit>` to check the remote branches, which gives the output `origin/v035`. It looks like the tag we're after is only reachable on the remote `origin/v035` branch.

If we checkout this branch locally, and run `git describe --tags`, we will get the output `v0.3.5`, we don't see the suffix described by the docs, because the tag points at the current commit (tip of the branch).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. The confusion is caused by the exact same commit having different hash in master (`d166ae3`) and v035 (`a6a1dd6`). Why would that happen at the first place?

Comment: Ah, interesting I, that is indeed confusing. There are a number of ways the commit itself could have happened but for the specifics in this case, it might require some repo investigation. It looks like https://github.com/google/glog/issues/187 and https://github.com/google/glog/pull/186 are worth reading; seems like some untested changes had been included in the master branch, but they didn't want to include them in the release at the time. They elected to create the release from that branch instead.

Comment: That's actually quite interesting, because last week I had been reading about a potential caveat with using the `git flow` workflow for release tagging and the effects it can have on `git describe` https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/49. Not quite what's happening in this case, just something I'd been thinking about =D

They probably just replayed that commit on a branch created from a point prior the unwanted changes, leading to a different commit hash.

Comment: I see so in a normal circumstances `git describe --tags` should just work. This is a problem of glog itself.

Comment: That's right, provided the tag is an ancestor of your current commit (head).